# I have a web server that I added letsencrypt ssl to. SSL works fine except for one page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, https

So I have a webserver that I added ssl to. There is domain.com with an associated vhost and sub.domain.com with an associated vhost. I used letsencrypt to add the ssl and it worked great. Used ./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone -d domain.com -d sub.domain.com The ssl is perfect on domain.com but not sub.domain.com. I added a redirect in the domain.com .htaccess file that looks like this. It is also in the sub.domain.com .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

When I type in domain.com it works like a charm. When I type in sub.domain.com it does not redirect. It just stays as http. But when I click on any link on the page, the https will appear. Just not when you go to any of the site links in the url bar. I have mybb on sub.domain.com and it set to https in mybb settings. It is like the rewrite is not working. Can anyone give some input?

Edit -

domain.com dir - /www/domain.com/html

sub.domain.com dir - /www/domain.com/forum

This is what is in the .htaccess file of the sub.domain.com

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>
```

Yes this .htaccess file is in the root of the directory.

Comment: How are your directories laid out? Where does the subdomain point in relation to the main domain? Are these the _only_ lines in the .htaccess? Does the directory serving as the docroot for the subdomain have its own separate htaccess?

Comment: Domain.com dir - /www/domain.com/html
sub.domain.com - /www/domain.com/forum

Here is the .htaccess file for the sub.domain.com. http://pastebin.com/zzitPZwk

Yes sub.domain.com has a separate .htaccess files.

@Michael

Comment: Please edit your original post above to include this information so everyone reading can find it quickly. Just include the relevant parts of the subdomain's .htaccess here instead of linking offsite.

Comment: Done @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Of I'm not mistaken, you probably only need to move the https condition and rule to occur first, before the index.php rewrite. Rewrite rules are highly order dependent.